# can use c++ write custom qml plugins in ubuntu sdk

Tags: ubuntu-touch, c++, qml, ubuntu-sdk

Recently, I want to develop a app for ubuntu showdown, but I want to use some plugins use
c++. So I want to write custom plugins, then I create a project with qml extension library. However, when I run it, it just pops up a dialog.

I have no reputation to upload an image, if you can do it self, you will know what I say.
I want to know whether I can use c++ in ubuntu touch apps, if I can, I want some examples.

Ps: I am new to qml and ubuntu sdk

Comment: Edit your question and add the code please. You can also upload the image to imgur.com and provide the link.

Comment: Currently, your question is a bit light on details. Tell us what plugins you intend to use, etc. You should edit your question and add as much specific details as much possible for us to be most helpful. You can upload the image to a image hosting website and link us to the image there.

Answer (score 1):

I just learned how to do this, and I wrote up what I learned [here](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/14/reading-files-with-a-c++-plugin-in-qml.html).  I'll repeat the basic ideas here.

Whichever C++ classes you wish to expose can be left mostly as is.  Any methods that you want exposed to QML need to be prefixed with `Q_INVOKABLE` in the header file.  To represent the plugin, you need a class that inherits from `QQmlExtensionPlugin` which has a `registerTypes` method that calls `qmlRegisterType` on each class to be exposed to QML.

The dialog you mention, was it this?

[image: Qt creator dialog]

If so, then for "Command" put `qmlscene` and for "Arguments", `-I <DIR> <QML>`, where `<DIR>` is the directory containing the plugin directory (likely `.`, the project directory) and `<QML>` is your main `.qml` file.  Again, see my [post](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/14/reading-files-with-a-c++-plugin-in-qml.html) for a more thorough explanation and a downloadable example.